# How to save user information (who, when, why) when deleting table record?

Tags: database

I want to save some user/application provided data (which **isn't accessible to database server**) when modifying table record for audit/history:

- user information (session_id, ...)
- application info (name, exe, ...)
- user's action which caused this modification (action_id, ...)

I added to the table fields to store this info and using direct SQL DML (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) statements to modify tables. Triggers insert records into history table after each modification.

When inserting or updating record I can save this information by sending it with **INSERT** or **UPDATE** statements. But when deleting this approach fails because we can't send 'user info' with **DELETE**.

**DELETE Triggers** have access only to database authorizations id (user/session_user), and that's not enough to identify actual person.

How to change my approach to save 'user info' when deleting record?

---

**Update**

Application: Visual FoxPro 9, Connect: ODBC, DB: DB2 for z/OS 10.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Question is DBMS agnostic.